# Acceleration perpendicular to constant velocity in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

In newtonian mechanics, if a body is  experiences an acceleration that is perpendicular to the direction of motion at all times, it moves in a circle and the magnitude of it's velocity does not change. How does this phenomenon look like with relativistic velocities?

Suppose that a body moves with constant velocity $ v_{xi} $ along the X-axis (in the coordinate frame of the body). If the body is then accelerated along the Y-axis with constant acceleration $a$, how does the velocity change? Of course, conservation of momentum also holds in special relativity, so the X-momentum should be conserved so that $ p_{xi} = \gamma_{i} m v_{xi} = \gamma_{f} m v_{xf} = p_{xf} $. Where $ \gamma_{i} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left( \frac{v_{xi}}{c} \right)^2}} $ and $ \gamma_{f} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left( \frac{v_{final}}{c} \right)^2}} $.
Is $ v_{final} $ in the relativistic case still $ v_{final} = \sqrt{ v_{xf}^2 + v_{yf}^2} $ ?
How does $v_{yf}$ depend on time and acceleration?

From what I have heard the trajectory of this motion is no longer circular but hyperbolic. I am interested in how this can be described quantitatively.

Comment: It seems your opening paragraph is about acceleration always perpendicular to the motion and then the rest is about constant acceleration on the Y axis with initial velocity only on the X. Did I misunderstand this?

Comment: So my question is about acceleration that is always perpendicular to the direction of motion assuming that the motion is always is X-direction, so I meant the coordinate-frame are attached to the body.

Comment: "no longer circular" - constant $\hat y$ acceleration with initial $\hat x$ velocity doesn't give you a circular (or hyperbolic) path in the non-relativistic regime either, it's parabolic. Recall freshman physics questions about projectile motion.

Answer (score 0):

Constant velocity on the x-axis doesn't affect anything with respect to the y axis. Constant acceleration on the y-axis would simply affect y-velocity the normal way. Total velocity is still $\sqrt{v^2_x + v^2_y}$.

If you want constant acceleration into the relativistic regime, you'd have to continuously increase the force. If you have a constant force, you would instead see a decreasing acceleration with $\gamma$.

The shape you describe would be neither a hyperbola nor a circle, just a quadratic curve.

Comment: I mean that the constant velocity on the X-axis is already relativistic. It is true that an increasing force is needed, because the inertia increases, but my assumption was that the acceleration is constant. If the X-component is relativistic, I don't think that the Y-component can simply be added.

Answer (score 0):

In Newtonian physics, constant acceleration along the Y axis leads to parabolic motion. The acceleration is not perpendicular to the velocity except momentarily when it's first applied. In circular motion, the acceleration isn't constant; only its magnitude is.

Extending the concept of constant (vector) acceleration to special relativity is not straightforward because [the four-acceleration of an accelerating object can't be constant](/a/625760); it is perpendicular to the four-velocity, which points in different directions at different times. But I think circular motion is what you're really interested in, and it's easier.

If you want the speed in some frame (length of the 3-velocity) to be constant, then you want

$$(\mathbf v - \mathbf{\hat t} (\mathbf{\hat t} \cdot \mathbf v))^2 = (\mathbf v' - \mathbf{\hat t} (\mathbf{\hat t} \cdot \mathbf v'))^2  \quad \text{where } \mathbf v' = \mathbf v + \mathbf a\,dτ$$

where all of the boldfaced quantities are 4-vectors. This ends up reducing to $\mathbf{\hat t} \cdot \mathbf a = 0$. In other words, the four-acceleration needs to have a $t$ component of $0$ in that frame. It also needs to be perpendicular to the four-velocity, as always. If you add two more constraints from Newtonian physics – that it's confined to a plane (zero $z$ component, say) and that its magnitude is constant – then the acceleration is completely determined (up to negation) and the object will move in a circle (or a helix in spacetime), just as in the Newtonian case. The magnitude of the acceleration has an extra factor of $γ$, so it goes to infinity as the object's 3-speed goes to $c$.